# How do I move the image in JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I am very new to the Java Swing, I want to move the image in JPanel by using MouseInputAdaptor. I google it but I couldn't find very simple version. I spent lot of time and I found that I should use mouseDragged, mousePressed methods but how can I applied to the specific image, suppose If attempt to drag how do I make that image move??

Please explain me?

Comment: "I couldn't fine very simple version". What does that mean? Not everything you do is simple. If the only code you found is complex, then maybe the task is complex. If you found code that works, what is wrong with using that? Otherwise post the code you found and explains why it is complex so we don't repeat ourselves and can maybe provide a better alternative. We can't guess what you think is complex about the code you already have.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mouseDragged()` method to do this.

Take two global variable `X` and `Y`. now in `paint method of JPanel` draw you image like this:

```
 public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
....
g.drawImage(image,X,Y,this);
....
}
```

and in your `mouseDragged` method do this:

```
 public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
          X = e.getX();
          Y = e.getY();
         repaint();
 }
```

Hope this helps.